# docker with sshd for testing

Tags: docker, ssh

I have a simple Docker file for setting up a server for testing some functionality with.  I need to get sshd up and running in order to do what I need to do:

```
FROM rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:18.04

RUN useradd -d /home/myuser -s /bin/bash myuser

COPY id_rsa.pub /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/myuser/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I run it using:

`docker run -p 8383:22 -i -t test:test`

When I attempt to connect to the server, I get the following:

```
$ > ~/.ssh/known_hosts && ssh -i ./id_rsa -p 8383 myuser@127.0.0.1
Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1 port 8383:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 127.0.0.1 port 8383
```

I have to restart the ssh server in the container after I run it (`service ssh restart`), but that's not a big deal and I can deal with that later.  My problem is why I can't ssh into the container.

Keys are really simple `ssh-keygen -b 4096`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with an image with ubuntu and sshd like [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd/)?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet.  I'll try that as a base and set up my user the same way.

Comment: Same error - I updated the Dockerfile setup above to reflect this.  Must be something with the user setup.

Comment: The usernames don't match. In the Dockerfile you are copying the id_rsa.pub into 'orbweavers' home directory, but when trying to connect you are using 'myuser'

Comment: oops, that was a mistake on my part copying the data over.  should not have included that in there.  :-/

Comment: Your container is running a bash shell, not an sshd server, so there won't be anything listening on port 22.

Comment: Removed `/bin/bash` and still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

After some long investigation I found the problem.  My ssh agent was interfering.  I can easily bypass it now by using:

```
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=true root@127.0.0.1 -p 8383
```